# How can I tell who owns a Ready to Install game?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

In the new Xbox One interface, there is a panel of Ready to Install games but I'm not sure why some games are there. I have other accounts on this Xbox but I can't tell which account owns what or whether the license is linked to this Xbox or another. Is there any easy way to tell which account or Xbox owns what?

Comment: @CamelCase: What Xbox 360 tag?

Comment: Sorry, been a long day

Answer (score 1):

I can help you in part from my experience.

The ready to install games will be relative to the signed in profiles.  Therefore, you can sign out profiles and check the changes.

For example, profile A and profile B are signed in.  You will see games for both profiles.  Sign out profile B.  You will now see games for profile A only.

I couldn't see another easy way to figure out who owned what from my experience.

In terms of the license, that is a complete mystery (even on the original Xbox 360).  I don't think there is a way to see a table of games vs. assigned console.  You can perform a license transfer to assign all games to the current console.

Comment: This isn't easy. Wish Microsoft made it easier. Also I just gave you the upvote that got you to 2k! Congrats!